# React not passing authorization header to rails api

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails-3, graphql, apartment-gem

I am using React frontend with a graphql rails api backend for a SaaS project with apartment. I need to get the authorization token from request.env so i can decode the user_id to get the tenant name which is a field in the User model. This is for a generic elevator based on the user logged in. When i inspect the Rails logger log I see that "HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"=>"" it's empty. what did i go wrong.

This is from the index.js where the authorization is added:

```
    const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
      const token = localStorage.getItem(AUTH_TOKEN)
      return {
        headers: {
          ...headers,
          authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
        }
      }
    })

    const client = new ApolloClient({
      link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
      cache: new InMemoryCache()
    })

    ReactDOM.render(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <ApolloProvider client={client}>
          <App />
        </ApolloProvider>
      </BrowserRouter>, 
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

And this is where I try to extract it in Rails:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use Apartment::Elevators::Generic, lambda { |request|
  tenant_name = nil 


  if request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]

    token = request.env["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]
    payload = JWT.decode token, Rails.application.secrets.secret_key_base, 'HS256'
    user_id = payload.first["user_id"]    
    tenant_name = User.find(user_id).subdomain
  end

  tenant_name
}
```